# I can not make the data insert into the database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery, mysqli

I am creating a comment form that will ask the user for his name, email and post a comment using php and mysqli for connecting to the database and the jquery for no refreshing but the problem is:
I can not make the data insert into the database but when I "echo" the variable that hold the data entered from the user it work fine without entered to the database and I do not know what is the error.

Can anyone help me?

**ps:**  I am not asking to write for me the code but I need to know how to solve it.

## submit_to_db.php

```
<?php
  $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'my_db');
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $name =isset ($_POST['name']);
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $comments = $_POST['comments'];

  echo"<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo"</pre>";

  $query = "INSERT into comments('email', 'comments') VALUES(?, ?)";
  echo $query;
  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  if($stmt->prepare($query)){

     $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $comments);
     $stmt->execute();
     //var_dump($stmt);

  }

  if($stmt){

  echo "thank you .we will be in touch soon <br />";
 // echo $_POST['name'];
  //echo $_POST['email'];
  //echo $_POST['comments'];
  var_dump($stmt);
  }
  else{
   echo "there was an error. try again later.";
   }  

}
else
   echo"it is a big error";
?>
```

## index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>feedback page</title>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href = "css/default.css" />

<script type = "text/javascript">

$(function(){

   $('#submit').click(function(){
     $('#container').append('<img src = "img/loading.gif" alt="Currently loading" id = "loading" />');

         var name = $('#name').val();
         var email = $('#email').val();
         var comments = $('#comments').val();


         $.ajax({

            url: 'submit_to_db.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'name =' + name + '&email=' + email + '&comments=' + comments,

            success: function(result){
                 $('#response').remove();
                 $('#container').append('<p id = "response">' + result + '</p>');
                 $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function(){
                     $(this).remove();
                 });

            }

         });         

        return false;

   });


});

</script>




</head>

<body>
   <form action = "submit_to_db.php" method = "post">
   <div id = "container">
      <label for = "name">Name</label>
      <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name" />

      <label for = "email">Email address</label>
      <input type = "text" name = "email" id = "email" />

      <label for = "comments">Comments</label>
      <textarea rows = "5"cols = "35" name = "comments" id = "comments"></textarea>
      <br />

      <input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "send feedBack" />
    </div>
   </form>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and whats the output from var_dump you have put in the code ?

Comment: i get the error from the first if that mean from if (isset($_POST['submit'])){...}      but if i remove the first if statment i get this                                          **thank you .we will be in touch soon
object(mysqli_stmt)[2]
  public 'affected_rows' => null
  public 'insert_id' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'param_count' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'errno' => null
  public 'error' => null
  public 'error_list' => null
  public 'sqlstate' => null
  public 'id' => null**

Comment: This code is similar/identical to the OP's post in another question.  I installed the scripts on my server and they do work.

Comment: See related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389888/php-mysql-insert-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bug Alert!**

If you do this:

```
$query = "INSERT into comments(email, comments) VALUES($email, $comments)";
```

and then do this:

```
 $stmt->bind_param('sss', $email, $comments);
```

you will probably get an error message.  You need to have bind place holders in the query string, which should look like:

```
$query = "INSERT into comments(email, comments) VALUES(?,?)";
```

and since you are only using two fields, your bind statement should read:

```
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $comments);
```

**Debugging Strategy**

```
 // Print out your post variable and look at it carefully...
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_POST);
 echo "</pre>";

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     //$name =isset ($_POST['name']);
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $comments = $_POST['comments'];
```

Look care fully at the name field, I found an extra/invisible character yesterday that was causing a problem.

Also, as a test to make sure the inserts work:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $name = "Stack Overflow";
     $email = "stack@overflow.com";
     $comments = "Lorem ipsum and so on...";
```

You need to find out if the problem is on the client side (the form and POST variables) or on the sever side (the MySQL stuff).

**My Version of Your Code**
Here is what I have working on my server. **Please review the comments.**  Be careful if you are cutting and pasting so that you don't introduce any extraneous characters.

```
<?php 
    // Echo your POST variable so you can see what the
    // data looks like from your submission form
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";

  $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
  $query = "INSERT into comments(name, email, comments) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

  // Initially, do a simple insert using static values to make sure 
  // the MySQL statements are working
  // When this works, you can comment these out and uncomment 
  // the statements using the POST array
  $name = "Some Name";
  $email = "some@name.com";
  $comments = "some commentary text...";

  // At this point, you will validate your input, but do this later...
  // After you tested the MySQL, try the form data
  //$name = $_POST['name'];
  //$email = $_POST['email'];
  //$comments = $_POST['comments'];

  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  if($stmt->prepare($query)){
     $stmt->bind_param('sss',$name, $email, $comments);
     $stmt->execute();
  }

  // This tells you if the insert worked...
  printf("%d Row inserted.<br>", $stmt->affected_rows);

  if($stmt->affected_rows){
  echo "thank you .we will be in touch soon";
  }
  else {
   echo "there was an error. try again later.";
  }  
?>
```

Comment: i updated my question look at the submit_to_db.php file   the system print out to me the message  a big error that mean that the submit was never post ....how is that  can be ??

Comment: Oh, good one.  Move the print_r to before your if statement, see my updated code above.

Comment: i did  as you said and i got this echo **Array
(
    [name_] => test name
    [email] => test email
    [comments] => test comments
)

it is a big error**

Comment: You still have a bug in our script related to `if($stmt)` - I discussed this earlier in one of your other questions that I responded to.  PLEASE review my previous comments.

Comment: Because you are using AJAX, the `submit` name is not part of the POST array... for the moment, remove that `if` statement since it is getting in the way.  You may add a validation step later.

Comment: added if($stmt->affected_rows) but nothing was changed

Comment: you mean i need to remove the if ($stmt)??  i did that but still nothing happen

Comment: I posted my working code.  Try the script before changing it.  Please accept this answer AND up vote it. Also, up vote my answer on your other question.  You are have gotten a lot of help from this forum, so acknowledge it. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

Please change your query as bellow :

```
$query = "INSERT into comments(`email`, `comments`) VALUES('$email', '$comments')";
```

Hope this will be helpful to you

Comment: try this : echo query in PHP script and alert the `result` in success function and let me know is it your query is correct or not

Comment: this is several line from the alert result  **thank you .we will be in touch soon <br /><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>object</b>(<i>mysqli_stmt</i>)[<i>2</i>]
  <i>public</i> 'affected_rows' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
  <i>public</i> 'insert_id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <font color='#3465a4'>null</font>  <i>public</i> 'param_count' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
  <i>public</i> 'num_rows' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <font color='#3465a4'>null</font>**